# How do I update code running as a daemon with zero downtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon

I have a Ruby daemon running which is collecting data, like temperatures. It collectes them every few seconds and, as soon as a minute is reached, it will calculate high, low and average values, which are then saved to a database. Also further calculations will be done in this step.

Now I would like to update the Ruby code and deploy it via some Capistrano magic.

The problem now is, if I just stop the daemon, I will not save the current minute to database. If I now start the new daemon, the minute has already been started, so I consider the first minute as "dirty" and will wait for the next full minute. So, basically, I have a gap now.

I could start a new process/daemon, starting to collect data. As soon as that got enough data, it will tell the old daemon to shut down. But how can I communicate between those two daemons?

I'd be cool if someone could point me to ideas regarding this.

A Rails app is also available, which is available in the browser. Ideally I would be able to talk to that as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a queue this queue server should have good uptime and there is one service which just writes to this queue so  the other process doing computation can have a little down time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule one: If you are collecting data you want to preserve across crashes and reboots, don't store it in memory. Get it outside your code as fast as possible and onto disk or somewhere more persistent.

Store your data in a database. It doesn't have to be fancy, it can be a simple SQLite database on disk.

I'd highly recommend looking into the [Sequel ORM gem](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), which makes it easy to work with a large number of DBMs.

Here's how easy it is to start using a disk-based SQLite database:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://temps.db')
```

If you have access to another DBM, use it. Sequel makes it easy, just get the data out of your code and stored.

Personally I'd have two tables and applications, the daemon to capture data and write it to the raw data table, and another that reads the raw data, summarizes it and writes it to a summary table. The second application would fire off periodically, probably as a cron job, summarizes all data received since the last summary, then quits.

Both tables have timestamp fields so its easy to check for new data.

You can figure out the rest.

---

You could look into using something like RabbitMQ as a back-end and send messages to it from your capture node(s), and have another node that reads the messages. I think that's over-engineering what is basically a simple problem, but it would be another way of making sure the data isn't lost across reboots and provide an alternate to using a database, but without any of the advantages of a database-centric design.

---

Regarding launching new code on the fly:

It's possible, but I'd still go with two or more apps talking to a database as mentioned above, to divide the capture and analysis functions. That way you can have multiple capture apps running in various places, without any chance of them stomping on the summarizing activity of another. One app would be in charge of summarizing data, whether there was one or one-million capture apps. That way you can take down one end or the other and the overall application will still function.

Using [`Signal.trap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Signal.html#method-c-trap) you can set an interrupt handler, such as HUP, and have that immediately relaunch the running code via [`exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec). I'd start with something like:

```
Signal.trap('HUP') { exec($0, ARGV) }
```

---

If you want to incorporate your Rails application, do it via the backing database your Rails application uses. Add the tables needed for your capture and analysis to that database, add a couple models to the Rails application, along with the associated forms/reports/pages and have your daemon and summarization code write to those tables to their heart's content.

Comment: Regarding this case, I could even have a second collection daemon running at another place, which I can query if the first is not available.... I'll check out sequel.

Comment: I think it's still the best solution - which I have implemented partly already. I was hoping for a more direct way. I can still use the "client" application as a daemon/loop to get new data quickly, instead of using a cronjob.

Comment: Feel free to create new questions regarding this, and refer to my tag in a comment to get my attention. Good luck.

Comment: @Jan-HendrikHeuing, I added some additional comments how to handle the other aspects of your question.

Comment: I have the original source exporting data to csv. Then a webservice like think to access those files. In my app, I have a collection deamon, writing to a local database, as well as a second daemon for handling anything else. So I can basically shut down any component.

Comment: Why write to CSV? Write directly to the database. Otherwise it sounds like a good start.